# Mpdf should not display page if it's empty

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I created a pdf document with 3 pages using Mpdf, the 1st page and 3rd page always contains data in it and for the 2nd page it depends. I don't want to show 2nd page if the data in it is empty

The below is the code structure

```
html = 'some html code to be printed on pdf'; //1st Page
$result[] = $html;

html2 = 'some html code to be printed on pdf'; //2nd Page (It might be empty)
$result[] = $html2;



//  if($pdfdetails['Test'] != "")
//  {
//  $htmlnewpage = $html2;
//  }else{
//  $htmlnewpage = '';
//  }

$result[] = $html2;

// In the second pdf, if the "if" condition is true then only the second page
   has to be displayed or else 3rd page should display (next page), 
   but it isn't working for me.


html3 = 'some html code to be printed on pdf'; //3rd Page
$result[] = $html3;

$mpdf = new mPDF("en-GB-x", [336, 190], "", "",30,30,30,30,6,3);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
$i=1;
$cnt = count($result);
foreach($result as $html){
$mpdf->AddPage("", [336, 190], "", "",10,10,10,4,1,0,'L');  
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
if($i < $cnt) {
    //$mpdf->AddPage('L');
}
$i++;
}

$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$mpdf->Output(test'.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
if($pdfdetails['Test'] != "")
{
$result[] = $html2;
}elseif($pdfdetails['Test'] == ""){

}

$result[] = $html3;
```